# How does Overdrive impact Affinity Chart of Blade?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

In Xenoblade Chronicles 2, there is the possibility to transfer non-plot Blade between Drivers. It is called Overdrive. Yet, I'm not sure how it works.

Most abilities of Blade are determined by the Affinity Chart. First Driver has to unlock tier of abilities by increasing Trust with Blade, then perform a specific action to unlock ability from tier. More of that, each ability has impact on Driver's mindset, by increasing a certain stat, e.g. Bravery or Compassion.

That's where numerous questions appear. I suppose, it would make sense, if trust between Blade and new Driver will be Rank E, but what about unlocked skills? If new Driver unlocks new set of skills, does he need to unlock each skill again, by performing same actions, or are skills becoming unlocked, if were unlocked by previous Driver? And what about mindset? Does mindset of previous Driver update? And last question - if Driver transfers Blade back to its previous owner, does Trust become Rank E, or keeps Trust Driver and Blade had before transferring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not affect it at all.

You can overdrive a blade and the level goes unchanged. The same happens if you release and find a rare blade again.

Another reason this is validated:

> When Rex gets the ability to control all blades, he can also raise their affinity.